# Changing home directory by editing /etc/passwd

Tags: fedora, home, etc

I am reading a book about Linux. It says that one of the ways (although not the best - I am aware that this can also be done with `usermod`) to change the home directory of a user is to change the home directory in `/etc/passwd` for that particular user. I have successfully changed the entry for a particular user to

`mainuser:x:1000:1000:mainuser:/home/mainuser/projects:/bin/bash`

However, upon logging into a shell as this user, I am positioned in `/home/mainuser` directory and not `/home/mainuser/projects`. Am I misunderstanding what home directory means? Shouldn't I be in `/home/mainuser/projects` when I log in?

Additional info:

Running Linux Fedora 25

grep mainuser /etc/passwd
`mainuser:x:1000:1000:mainuser:/home/mainuser/projects:/bin/bash`

`$ getent passwd mainuser`
`mainuser:x:1000:1000:mainuser:/home/mainuser/projects:/bin/bash`

Comment: does the "projects" directory exist? if existing check the uid and the gid with the command "ls -l"

Comment: yes, it exists, UID and GID (third and fourth column) is mainuser.

Comment: Should work as you describe. Can you post your linux version, the entry of that user in the passwd file, the output of `getent passwd mainuser`, `ls -l /home/mainuser/projects`, and the exact comand how you login with that user and its output.

Comment: Ahhh, you need to restart your computer. Just quitting bash isn't enough. Thanks for help.

Comment: You don't need to restart the computer, but you do need to log into a new login shell, which is _definitely_ accomplished by rebooting, but could also be gotten by logging out and in again.

Comment: Last line has a typo. It says main*suer* instead of main*user*. Don't think that's your problem, but... who knows?

Comment: Is there a second account with same login name?